# Gradle tasks have no actions available in Eclipse

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I have a gradle project and I want to run actions such as "clean build" etc.
However, the gradle tasks are showing no actions available when I am trying to invoke the action.

Comment: can you please share the result of `gradle clean build` command?

Comment: gradlew clean build works from the command line.. but gradle clean build is resulting in a is not recognized as an internal or external command. I want to run the clean build from Eclipse.. edited the question.

Comment: Are you sure you have installed gradle?

Comment: @Uladzislau Kaminski I haven't for this particular project. I set the gradle path in the preferences and it is working fine now.. thanks :-)

Comment: my congratulations!

Comment: Please share in particular what error you are getting.